# Why do I get an UnboundLocalError in my function?

Tags: python

I am newbie, trying to learn python.

According to this article http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm, I get an UnboundLocalError in the following code but I don't understand why:

```
Money = 2000
def AddMoney():
   # Uncomment the following line to fix the code:
   # global Money
   Money = Money + 1

print Money
AddMoney()
print Money
```

But the below code works fine

```
Money = 2000
def AddMoney():
   # Uncomment the following line to fix the code:
   # global Money
   Money = 1

print Money //2000
AddMoney()
print Money //2000
```

They explain things in the article, but I'm still not sure that I understand. *Why* do I get an `UnboundLocalError` in the first example, but not in the second?

Comment: Read about function scope and global variables

Comment: @SterlingArcher i learned it.i am trying to understand it. But y second one is working, first one not. Can you brief me some more?

Comment: When you have an actual error, it's good form to post the full stack trace. For such a trivial example we can figure it out, but on more complicated problems the full trace will be invaluable.

Comment: The second one **runs**, but it's not **working** as such - the `Money` inside `AddMoney` does not affect the `Money` outside, it just shadows it!

Comment: Y am i down voted here.

Comment: @Sathish my guess is because someone glanced at the question and thought you were asking why you were getting the error, instead of **why** you were getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the article does explain a little bit, but not very much about **why**.

When you're programming and you write the name of something, the computer has to know *where* to go look for that thing. The *where* is a term known as **scope**. All variables in Python have a scope. Here are some examples to illustrate:

```
from __future__ import print_function

value = 'blue'

def fun():
    value = 'yellow'
    print("Value in function: ", value)

print("Value before: ", value)
fun()
print("Value after: ", value)

# Output:
#
# Value before:  blue
# Value in function:  yellow
# Value after:  blue
```

In this script you define `value` to be 'blue'. Then inside the function you set it to 'yellow'. But why does it not stay 'yellow' after the function is called? Scoping.

When you define `value = 'yellow'` in your function, the name `value` is bound to `'yellow'` *only* inside the current block (a function, in this case). You'll hear the terms *shadow* or *hiding* to explain what's happening here, because that's effectively what's happening. You are hiding the original `value` with a new `value`, but once your function ends, so does your new value.

You can see this by using the `globals()`and `locals()` builtins

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint

value = 'blue'

def fun():
    print("Globals in function: ")
    pprint(globals())
    print("Locals in function: ")
    pprint(locals())

    value = 'yellow'
    print("Value in function: ", value)

    print("Globals at end of function: ")
    pprint(globals())
    print("Locals at end of function: ")
    pprint(locals())

print("Globals before function: ")
pprint(globals())
print("Locals before function: ")
pprint(locals())

print("Value before: ", value)
fun()
print("Value after: ", value)

print("Globals after function: ")
pprint(globals())
print("Locals after function: ")
pprint(locals())
```

Now, python has a `global` keyword that allows you to tell Python that instead of looking inside the *local* scope, you want to look in the *global* scope for these variables:

```
from __future__ import print_function

value = 'blue'

def fun():
    global value
    value = 'yellow'
    print("Value in function: ", value)

print("Value before: ", value)
fun()
print("Value after: ", value)

# Output:
#
# Value before:  blue
# Value in function:  yellow
# Value after:  yellow
```

In Python, it will try to resolve names first in the local scope, and then in the global scope, which means you can write something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

value = 'blue'

def fun():
    print("Value in function: ", value)

print("Value before: ", value)
fun()
print("Value after: ", value)

# Output:
#
# Value before:  blue
# Value in function:  blue
# Value after:  blue
```

But if that works, then why doesn't your first example, with `Money = Money + 1`? The answer is simple, though perhaps unexpected:

Because you are trying to redefine `Money` in your function (the `Money =` part), it cannot go look for your variable in the global scope, because it doesn't know if you meant to use the global version or the local version, and you get an `UnboundLocalError`. So you need to tell Python what you mean: Did you want to use the global version, or should you be using something locally?

By declaring `global Money`, you tell Python explicitly that you want to use the global version. But if you want to use something local then you'll need to use a different name, or define `Money` before you try to use it as in `Money + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

AddMoney doesnt know Money variable has been defined before so it crashes with `local variable 'Money' referenced before assignment` thinking is a local variable which should have been declared inside `AddMoney class`.

If you uncomment the `global Money` line inside AddMoney class it will work.

Also the second example is working because in the line `Money = 1` you are not using Money variable, you are just asigning a value to Money and overriding the global value

Comment: Using Money and assigning a value to Money is Diff?

Comment: Exactly, in this line Money = Money + 1 you assume Money has been already defined where AddMoney doesnt know anything about because that class cant "see" the Money = 2000 above it. But when you use Money = 1 you are just defining a new variable

Comment: @Sathish whether variable is local or global, is defined during the function compilation. If you assign to a variable, it becomes local unless explicitly declared `global`.

Answer (score 1):

Preface: I'm going with the assumption that the space before `Money = 2000` in the second snippet is a mistake, because whitespace is significant in Python, but I don't think it actually makes a change here.

In your first example `Money = Money + 1` is trying to read from a variable and then assign a new value to it. `Money` doesn't exist in the local scope, so it throws an error. The second example is only assigning a value to a variable. `AddMoney()` creates a local variable called `Money` and then does nothing with it. The `Money` from the outer scope is unchanged, as your comments indicate.

Comment: So python executes the expression form left to right? so in Money + 1, Money is not exist in the local scope. So it throws that error? Am i rite?

Comment: I would say it executes the right side of the assignment first, but yes, that is why it throws an error there.

Comment: When the function is *run*, the right-hand side is evaluated first. However, when the function is first *defined*, the assignment causes `Money` to be marked as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the conflict between globals and local scope variables
(As others have said)
declaring money as global in the function shall do good

```
Money = 2000
def AddMoney():
    global Money
    Money = Money + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In both functions, you need to delete the hashtag in the line '# global Money' in order for the function to work properly. Hashtags in Python cause the rest of the line to be 'commented', which are lines that will not affect your code and instead act as notes to the developer.

This code will work properly:

```
Money = 2000
def AddMoney():
   # Uncomment the following line to fix the code:
   global Money
   Money = Money + 1

print Money
AddMoney()
print Money
```

In your second piece of code, the function isn't redefining the variable money outside of the function's environment, so while an error is not appearing, you are not accomplishing what you want with the code. Again, deleting the hashtag (uncommenting) will solve your problem. This code will work:

```
Money = 2000
def AddMoney():
   # Uncomment the following line to fix the code:
   global Money
   Money = 1

print Money //2000
AddMoney()
print Money //2000
```

Hope this helps!